# How can i pass parameters to an injectable constructor in Java?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I have been using manual dependency injection for a while now, and I started to look into the @Inject annotation from javax (JSR330).

Si I had something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(DepA depA, DepB depB) {
        this.depA = depA;
        this.depB = depB;
    }
}
```

And to use it I was instantiating it like this:

```
public void myMethod() {
    DepA depA = new DepA();
    DepB depB = new DepB();
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(depA, depB);
}
```

However, it starts getting messy when my dependencies have dependencies, so I read a bit and went with this (everyone seems to agree that injectable constructor is a best practice):

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {}

    @Inject
    public MyClass(DepA depA, DepB depB) {
        this.depA = depA;
        this.depB = depB;
    }
}
```

And used it like this:

```
public void myMethod() {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
}
```

This seems to work like a charm, but there is a use case missing and I couldn't find the answer: what if I want to inject dependencies **and** use a *real* parameter in my constructor?

For instance, is something like this possible:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(String aContextualValue) {}

    @Inject
    public MyClass(DepA depA, DepB depB, String aContextualValue) {
        this.depA = depA;
        this.depB = depB;
        this.aContextualValue = this.aContextualValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `MyClass` would be managed by the DI, where would `aContextualValue` come from?

Comment: @lexicore that is the subject of my question. I guess I am looking for something like partial injection? The more I think about it, the more I believe there is no other way than using field injection for my dependencies, and the constructor for my contextual parameters.

Comment: Please don't overtheoretize yet. I just want to know where does `aContextualValue` come from? Do you read it from some config file or get it from the user or what?

Comment: @lexicore Oh I misunderstood the question, I think it would come from the user most of the time.

Comment: So if `aContextualValue` will come from the user, how can it be managed by the DI container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If (as you say in comments) `aContextualValue` comes from the user, you can't really inject it. So you can't fully let the DI container manage the `MyClass`.

What you can do instead is implement something like `MyClassFactory` which would produce `MyClass`es for you.

Something like:

```
public class MyClassFactory {

    private final DepA depA;
    private final DepB depB;

    public MyClassFactory(DepA depA, DepB depB) {
        this.depA = depA;
        this.depB = depB;
    }

    public MyClass createMyClass(String aContextualValue) {
        return new MyClass(this.depA, this.depB, aContextualValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great! I was hoping there would be a way to avoid writing too much, but this does what I asked :)

Comment: With this "traditional" (non-cdi approach) you can not inject a MyClass instance into some other places or am I missing something? What am I supposed to do if I would like to inject a MyClass instance after it was created with a constructor parameter value supplied by a user?